# nested switch case not working

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I am trying to execute some commands using USART communication and reading some values using ATmega32-A. have a look at my code . My problem is i am trying to add some cases (nested switch case) but i am not getting what i want. I hope i am giving all most all information required to solve my problem.

```
void uniCom(void) {
switch (Command) {
/* ... */
case (muxsel):
  printf(muxselection);
  switch (c) {
    case 1:
      printf("this is mux chaneel1");
      DDRB = 0b10111111;
      PORTB = 0b00000000;
      printf("adc Value", ReadAdc());
      Command = 0;
      break;
    case 2:
      /*-------------------*/
      break;
  }
  Command = 0;
break;
/* ... */
default:
    Command = 0;
    break;
}
```

}
The problem is undefined c. And I don't see any declaration of muxselection, maybe missing "" ? Now the second approach.

```
void selcase(void) {
unsigned char c;
printf("muxselection");
while (rx_counter0) {
 c = getchar();
switch (c) {
  case 1:
    printf("this is mux chaneel1");
    DDRB = 0b10111111;
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    printf("adc Value", ReadAdc());
    Command = 0;
    break;
  case 2:
    /*-------------------*/
    break;
}
}
}
void uniCom(void) {
switch (Command) {
/* ... */
case (muxsel):
  printf(muxselection);
  selcase();
  Command = 0;
  break;
/* ... */
default:
    Command = 0;
    break;
}
}
```

My problem is i am executing all the commands as i declared but i want to select some more cases in one of the main switch case command "muxsel". for that i wrote nested switch case. if i select "muxsel" command on hyperteminal then it is printing like "muxselection" then if i enter 1 to select "case '1'"in second switch, nothing is printing. it is printing "command not found". what is the problem. I want execute nested switch but i am not able to do that using above code I have tried like this also.

```
void selcase(void) {
         unsigned char c;
         printf("muxselection");
         while (rx_counter0) {
         c = getchar();

         switch (c) {
                  case '1':
                    printf("this is mux chaneel1");
                    DDRB = 0b10111111;
                    PORTB = 0b00000000;
                    printf("adc Value", ReadAdc());
                    c= 0;
                    break;
                  case '2':
                  /*-------------------*/
                  break;
                 default;
                  break;
               }
            }
          }
```

creating one function for nested switch case and calling in main switch case as shown below.

```
  void uniCom(void) {
      switch (Command) {
                 /* ... */
                   case (muxsel):
                          printf(muxselection);
                          selcase();
                          Command = 0;
                          break;
                     /* ... */
                     default:
                       Command = 0;
                       break;
         }
       }
```

this way also not working please suggest me how to overcome this problem. i want to select one of the command in main switch case such as "muxsel" after that i have select mux channels using case statement. any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have solved this problem.

Comment: Your indentation is quite far away from awesome, making it a bit hard to read the code.

Comment: Does the case with the altered `case(muxsel):` even compile ? I see no place where the `c` would come from for the `switch(c)`. Not to mention `case 2: ----` but i assume it's a place holder.

Comment: Command is a global variable? *this code was written by an expert*

Comment: Maybe its a global not by choice of the code writer. This looks like a complete code. There is no `#include` and no declaration of it ... Well it sure looks strange. Or am I missing something. Same goes for `status`. It it this default int type compilers often warn about when you put a typo in a variable's name ?

Comment: I somehow edited the code to correct the indentation.. Very difficult since OP put some much blocks in partial state, without the closing brace..

Comment: I'm guessing that you forgot to add `muxsel' to the 'cmdList' array?  When you call help, does your new command appear in the list?

Comment: @Ross I have added muxsel in cmdList array, that you can see. but when i call help function muxsel is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... the code isn't terribly clear, but I **think** I see your problem. 
You tried to modify the code like this:

```
case (muxsel):
 printf(muxselection);
  switch (c) {
     case 1:
         printf("this is mux chaneel1");
         DDRB = 0b10111111;
         PORTB = 0b00000000;
         printf("adc Value", ReadAdc());
         Command = 0;
         break;
     case 2:
```

First, you don't have `c` declared in the scope of the `uniCom()` function. So that would not compile. Because you didn't give full code I *assume* you know that and probably really did something like this:

```
void uniCom(void) {

    unsigned char c;
    c = getchar();  

    switch (Command) {
      case (no_com):
          Command = 0;
    ....
      case (muxsel):
          printf("muxselection\n"); //Need quotes here and maybe a \n?
          switch (c) {
             case 1:
              ...
```

Which leads to the next problem. You're asking for a char `c` but your cases are built on an `int`. For example, if the user enters 3, what you're getting is the character '3' or the int 51. Check the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

So your cases are for start of header (SOH), start of text (STX), etc right now... that's not going to work the way you wanted it to. You need to either do this:

```
          switch (c) {
             case 51:     // This is ASCII '1'
              ...
              break;
             case 52:     // This is ASCII '2'
```

Or do this:

```
          switch (c) {
             case '1':
              ...
              break;
             case '2':
```

Since you didn't give your input, or how c was defined, I could be wrong... but I'm going to wager that's your problem. By the way, make sure you have a `default` case at the end with a message like "bad input", it makes this type of thing easier to catch.

**EDIT:**
Modify the code as follows and share the result:

```
void runCom(void){
      unsigned char c;
      c = getchar();
      printf("%c %d\n", c, c);   //<-- add this line here
      switch(Command){
```

and

```
void selcase(void) {
    unsigned char c;
    printf("muxselection");
    while (rx_counter0) {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%c %d\n", c, c); //<-- and this line here
        switch (c) {
```

Comment: yes, thanks for reply, i have declared as you said and tried but still not executing the inside switch. My problem is i am executing all the commands as i declared but i want to select some more cases in one of the main switch case command "muxsel". for that i wrote switch case as i described earlier. if i select "muxsel" command on hyperteminal then it is printing like "muxselection" then if i enter 1 to select "case '1'"in second switch, nothing is printing. it is printing "command not found".

Comment: @verendra - OK, first, see the edit. I don't see you consuming any newline characters, so add the extra `getchar()` call after every time you get a character `c` right now. If that *still* fails, then we need more code. Please add your new code in whole so we can stop guessing.

Comment: Now i have clearly added my complete code and problem. Please can you have a look at and suggest me.

Comment: @verendra - You are still going to have the problem I mentioned in my edit. The first time you run `getchar()` you're going to get what was typed, the next time you're going to get the `'\n'` character. You need to consume the newline character as I mentioned. Try printing `c` so you can see what I mean. After you get it each time add this line: `printf("%c %d\n", c, c);` the second time you get `c` you'll see it's "10" which is a newline character. Not what you wanted.

Comment: yes even i have tried still it is displying "command not found".may be these cases or not in the command list. is that the reason?. I don't think so...

Comment: @verendra - OK, I'm not seeing what's wrong, so I changed my edit, please copy and paste those lines into your two methods, run the program, then share your output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, No need of using getchar(); two times. now i have resolved my problem. thanks alot for your help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it as an answer 'cause there is no place for it in comments. Although it's definitely not a final satisfactory once, it might help you get there.

For now I see two problems. You say you tried altering `case(muxsel)`. Your code cannot even compile in my opinion. The code for the function should look similar to this:

```
void uniCom(void) {
  switch (Command) {
    /* ... */
    case (muxsel):
      printf(muxselection);
      switch (c) {
        case 1:
          printf("this is mux chaneel1");
          DDRB = 0b10111111;
          PORTB = 0b00000000;
          printf("adc Value", ReadAdc());
          Command = 0;
          break;
        case 2:
          /*-------------------*/
          break;
      }
      Command = 0;
    break;
    /* ... */
    default:
        Command = 0;
        break;
  }
}
```

The problem is undefined `c`. And I don't see any declaration of `muxselection`, maybe missing `""` ?
Now the second approach.

```
void selcase(void) {
  unsigned char c;
  printf("muxselection");
  while (rx_counter0) {
    c = getchar();
    switch (c) {
      case 1:
        printf("this is mux chaneel1");
        DDRB = 0b10111111;
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        printf("adc Value", ReadAdc());
        Command = 0;
        break;
      case 2:
        /*-------------------*/
        break;
    }
  }
}
void uniCom(void) {
  switch (Command) {
    /* ... */
    case (muxsel):
      printf(muxselection);
      selcase();
      Command = 0;
      break;
    /* ... */
    default:
        Command = 0;
        break;
  }
}
```

The second case could compile probably. The thing I do not understand is, why in the 2nd case you do manually read `c`. While in the former you do not ? Should it be loaded within `uniCom` routine or not ? It sure is in `getCom()`. Maybe you should not mess with buffers from the level of `uniCom` or below. Also are you sure that `while(rxcounter0)` will ever stop ? And if `getchar()` means to read a character from standard input from a human user typing on a keyboard it might be hard to read 1 or 2 from him as these are pretty low ASCII codes not present there.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I think you understand my problem. If i am trying with second approach it is excuiting infinite times but not entering into selcase(); for muxselection there is no declaration means as you said "" missing.

Comment: The thing I do not understand is, why in the 2nd case you do manually read c. While in the former you do not ?  i can't understand properly your question.